# Django allow anonymous ajax request to access a Generic View

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, rest

This is what I've got so far:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class ConfigurationView(View):

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ConfigurationView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

However, when I make an ajax get request to this view I am **not able to access the get method**

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://{{ domain }}/configure",
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {
    email: "{{ email }}",
  },
  dataType: "json"
})
```

I think I am sending the `csrftoken` correctly and I shouldn't really need the `csrf_exempt`, but either way the request gets a redirection to the login page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If it gets redirected to the login page, then it is not the issue of csrf. Check whether any permission class or settings applied to the view

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Currently there aren't any permission_classes. I've tried adding  a new permission class (IsReadOnly), but it doesn't even get inside the permission class

Comment: I'm wandering whether that needs to go through some sort of a middleware that would allow those endpoints

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't really the `csrftoken` but rather I had to implement a middleware to handle those anonymous endpoints:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class AuthMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    anonymous_whitelist = [
        '/<django_app>/configure',
    ]

    def anonymous_allowed(self, path):
        if path in self.anonymous_whitelist:
            return True

        return False
```